# How to hide Airplay devices in Audio Output list on Macos Catalina?

Tags: catalina, audio, airplay

*This was asked many years ago but previous answers are not applicable to Catalina so I'd like to reopen it.*

Is there a way to entirely disable Airplay in Catalina, or by some other means arrange that long lists of Airplay devices will not appear in the list of available Audio output devices?

Background: When I'm at my desk I want to select between audio devices connected to my Mac and  I do not want to see in my device list long lists of Apple TVs, Rokus, Smart TVs, and other people's Apple Computers.  When I'm in the office the list is ridiculously long and it's useless and annoying to see the Macbooks and Smart TVs of various random people on other floors of the building as available audio devices.